# Why am I getting this error when uploading to bigquery

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

Every time I try uploading my csv file I get the same error. Error while reading data, error message: Error detected while parsing row starting at position: 5889. Error missing close quote character(")

My table only goes up to 3787, but I deleted rows 5889 and all the rows surrounding it. I also did control f and got rid of any apostrophes or possible missing quotes

Answer (score 0):

Are you uploading to by a CLI ? Can you try adding `--allow_quoted_newlines` flag ? You can follow this guide [here.](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_table) (You can see other flags there too, that might be helpful to your use case)

Sample:

```
    bq load \
    --source_format=CSV \
    --allow_quoted_newlines \
    mydataset.mytable \
    gs://mybucket/mydata.csv \
    ./myschema.json
```